# How to export a variable after editing it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I need to export an auth provider, but after modifying its settings.
I tried this, using React, but it gave me two errors:
*"Parsing error: Unexpected token"

"Support for the experimental syntax 'exportDefaultFrom' isn't currently enabled"*

```js
const facebookAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

facebookAuthProvider.setCustomParameters({
  'display': 'popup'
});

export facebookAuthProvider;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: But what's wrong with this export?

Comment: It's quite normal to export things after initializing them.

Comment: @Barma Updated the question

Comment: @heleg ........

Comment: Probably, you aren't using any compiler. Try to `export default` instead just export